# Suppress the automated creation of sections in R studio (code-folding)

Tags: r, code-folding

I am using the subsection functionality in R studio to structure my coding. On my apple, I do this with COMMAND + SHIFT + R. However, R studio also creates a subsection for me automatically when I enter a 'fixed' code structure, such as this:

```
####################### THE VALIDATION SET APPROACH #######################
```

I don't want this, since my code becomes really messy with all the subsections.

Also, this happens when writing a for loop.

```
library(ISLR)
library(boot)

cv.error <- rep(0, 5)
for(i in 1:5) {
  glm.fit <- glm(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, i), data = Auto)
  cv.error[i] <- cv.glm(Auto, glm.fit)$delta[1]
              }
cv.error
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Comment: You can simply use a differnce code structure, specifically no more than 4 `#`. For example it could be `#++++++++++++++++++ abc ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, though I am still wondering if there's a way to undo the automatic classifying the code as a section

Comment: Also, this doesn't work with specific functions that automatically code into a section (for example, the for loop, see adjusted question)

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is with that for loop

Comment: If you copy-paste the code to R studio, you see that the for loop is collapsed into a section

Comment: You can collapse it, but it's not a section. You cannot select it as you can select real sections.

Comment: You are right :)